# Passing variables in delete route results in "Page Not Found" Error - Laravel

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5.7

I am trying to provide delete functionality. 
When the user clicks on the delete icon of a particular element, the element should be deleted from the database.

The view file

```
 @if(Auth::user()->id == $ad->user_id)

      <a href = '{{url("/ad/{$ad->id}/delete")}}'><i class="fas fa-trash-alt" style = "color : red; float : right;"></i></a>

 @endif
```

web.php file

```
Route::get('/ad/{$id}/delete',function($id) {

     Ad::where('id',$id)->delete();

     return redirect()->route('dashboard');

 })->middleware('auth');
```

If the same function is carried out without passing the variable to it, it works just fine.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to change 
Route::get('/ad/{$id}/delete

to 
Route::get('/ad/{id}/delete

That is, I had to remove the $ symbol.